# Fixed-Size Box With Scrollbars on HTML Page?

Tags: html

I'm sure there's a simple answer to this... or not:

I have a site that is a fixed height. I wish to have another box inside the site with scrollable HTML. One way to do this is with an iFrame, but I'd like to specify the HTML inline (i.e., not use an external file). Is there any other HTML tag (or similar) that will allow me to do this?

If I am [barking up the wrong tree](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/56150.html) here, that might also be helpful to know: how do you get long text into a fixed layout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could achieve all this with a sized `<div>` element and scroll bars being enabled.

```
<style>    
div { 
    overflow: auto; 
    height: 500px; 
    width: 500px;
    } 
</style>    

<div>Content goes here</div>
```

Comment: So is this the answer? or just a +1 from you?